# Unable to Evaluate Expression - Visual Studio Debug Mode

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I keep getting the following when trying to step through code and use the Immediate Window or Watch Window in Visual Studio.

> Unable to Evaluate the Expression

I'm using Visual Studio 2008.  Searching the forums there is a lot of talk of using the overloaded Response.Redirect and passing false to the endResponse parameter.  I have tried that

I have also checked that my code is running the debug version and not the complied version.

I decided to start a brand new Windows Form Application with nothing on the form.  In the Form Load event I declare a String and set a value to it.  Stopping in there via a breakpoint I try and print the value of the String to the Immediate window and I still get 'Unable to Evaluate the Expression'

This has occurred all of a sudden.  Regardless of any solution I open I am unable to use the Immediate window or watch windows to determine values in the code.

I'm not sure If a setting in Visual Studio has changed?

Answer (score 4):

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Just My Code

If the option is not ticked, then I get "Unable to evaluate the expression".

If I tick the option **AND restart visual studio** (this is the crucial bit) it fixes the problem for me.

Comment: Ha, had this issue 6 months later, remembered I'd posted the answer here on stack overflow, and managed to dig up the answer again!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with Visual Studio 2012, and fixed it just resetting settings: ["Unable to evaluate the expression" in Visual Studio 2012 Debug Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23763921/926064)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by selecting a non-Web project in Solution Explorer

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be in a VB.NET project, things are a bit confusing. The **Memory** window *shows* the address in C(++)/C# syntax (for instance `0x000002287A44BDB0`). But you have to *type* Basic syntax (`&H000002287A44BDB0`)!

Even when you just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> inside the **Address** textbox on the existing value, you will get:

> Unable to evaluate the expression.

Just remember to change the `0x` into `&H` and all will be fine.