# "Unable to evaluate the expression" in Visual Studio 2012 Debug Mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

My Visual Studio 2012 installation has unexpectedly started to show the message "Unable to evaluate the expression" everywhere where we watch variables in debug mode.

I already tried to change some debug settings, as proposed by some fixes, but the problem stays there.

Some others fixes recommend us to re-install visual studio, which I wouldn't like to do. What more can we do to fix it ?

Comment: my answer here might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/38001451/16676

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A reset in all my visual studio settings using ***"tools -> import and export settings"*** (which allow you to save the current settings before reset).

After the reset my debug issue was fixed. Then I imported my saved settings and the problem stays fixed keeping all my original settings.

Comment: ... which means that there's a setting that has changed during the reset that is affecting this. The question is: which one?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and in my case it appeared that several devenv.exe instances were running, which caused the issue.